atomic tactics : restore previous state if tactic didn't solve the current goal in Coq
I am trying to learn how to combine Ltac tactics in Coq and have run into an annoying problem.
Unless I use now, it is very common for custom tactics, at least the extremely naive ones that I write by chaining together random stuff with ;, to modify the proof state even if they didn't succeed in closing the goal.
I would like to write an atomic tactic that either succeeds in closing the current goal or restores the previous proof state.
For example, I have the following, adapted from this fantastic answer.
Require Import Lia.

Ltac combo := (congruences || idtac) ; intuition ; gintuition ; firstorder ; (lia || idtac) ; eauto.

Ltac finisher := try (intros ; combo).

The finisher tactic above cannot close the proof below.
Theorem example : forall n m, 2 * m = 3 * n.
Proof.
  finisher.
Abort.

However, we can still see the consequences of running intros after finisher has run.
Is there a way to make finisher atomic?

You can do that with solve (the doc is here, as in
Ltac finisher := try solve [ intros ; combo ].


The tactic combinator try is meant not to fail whatever happen, you want to use solve [tac1 | ... | tacn ] instead that fails if it does not solve the goal.
Require Import Lia.

Ltac combo := (congruence || idtac) ; intuition ; gintuition ; firstorder ; (lia || idtac) ; eauto.

Ltac finisher := solve [ intros ; combo ].

Theorem example : forall n m, 2 * m = 3 * n.
Proof.
  finisher.
Abort.

Note that:

it is important to always wrap finisher tactics / solvers with solve to detects error when refining code and avoid side effects in case of failure like above
if you want a finisher tactic specialised for your purpose, you can just redefine now writing Ltac now ::= finisher, but then be sure to wrap it in solve no to break now invariant that it solves the goal or fails

There is no tutorial in Coq Platform docs about combining tactics yet, but the refman explains quite well the different predefined tactics combinator that are provided with Ltac1 https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.20.0/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#control-flow

A common alternative practice is to add ; [] at the end of a tactic supposed to solve a goal. That said solve is more general since it tries several tactics.
